# How do I see more details about exactly what the Firebase JavaScript client is doing?

Tags: firebase

I want more insight into what the Firebase JavaScript client library is doing.

I'm developing a JavaScript app using Firebase that has to deal with a lot of complexity. For example, it has to handle network disruptions and intermittent periods of high latency. The client library is handling this, but I want to know more about how it's doing that.

Is there a way to enable verbose logging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! You can enable debugging logs like this:

```
Firebase.enableLogging(true);
```

You can either add that to the source code for your app, or paste it into your web browser's JavaScript console.

Once enabled, the Firebase client library prints a whole bunch of logs to your JavaScript console.

**Note:** It's probably not a good idea to run this in production. It increases the bandwidth that clients use considerably.