# Limitation of free plan in firebase

Tags: firebase

What is the meaning of the following?
50 Max Connections, 5 GB Data Transfer, 100 MB Data Storage.
Can anyone explain me?  Thanks

**EDIT - Generous limits for hobbyists**
[Firebase has now updated the free plan limits](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)
Now you have
100 max connections
10 GB data transfer
1 GB storage

Comment: Update: Firebase now provides 100 max connections, 10GB transfer and 1GB storage in free plan

Comment: my "usage" shows bandwidth 66.18 GB, Storage 45.6MB, peak connections 12. I'm on free plan. Seems like they don't look at usage every hour or day

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 35):

That means that you can have only 50 active users at once, only 5GB data to be transferred within one month and store only 100 MB of your data.
i.g. you have an online web store: only 50 users can be there at once, only 100 mbytes of data (title, price, image of item) can be stored in DB and only 5 GB of transfer - means that your web site will be available to deliver to users only 5gb of data (i.e. your page is 1 mbyte size and users will be able to attend that page only 50 000 times).
UPD: to verify the size of certain page (to define if 5gb is enough for you) - using google chrome right click anywhere on page - "Inspect Element" and switch to tab "Network". Then refresh the page. In bottom status bar you will amount of transferred data (attached size of current stackoverflow page, which is 25 kbytes)
[image: stackoverflow question page]

Comment: Client-side monitoring can provide an initial estimate for the numbers. Bot for the real values that Firebase uses, you should check the Analytics tab of your Firebase's Dashboard page. E.g. one of mine now says that I'm at 1.63 MB data stored, 138.38 MB Bandwidth used (in the last 30 days) and 2 Peak concurrent users (in the last 30 days).

Comment: Using FIrebase Dashboard will provide more accurate statistics definitely, but client-side monitoring will help to identify if provided bandwidth gonna be enough for you or not. Just kind of preliminary statistics for preliminary calculations

Comment: Agreed, client-side monitoring is best to gain insight into what is causing the traffic. Enabling Firebase's client-side debugging might also be helpful for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022086/can-a-firebase-client-determine-the-bytes-sent-and-received and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634570/how-do-i-see-more-details-about-exactly-what-the-firebase-javascript-client-is-d/25634571#25634571

Comment: When does a firebase connection start and stop? And here is an explanation in firebase FAQ , **1 concurrent corresponds to roughly 1,400 monthly visits.**, what does this sentence mean ?

Comment: it means that one concurrent connection will be enough if you expect less than 1400 visits per month. In case, if you expect 10,000 visits (usages of your app) - you need approximately 8 concurrent connections. I.g. you downloaded and app and it send one request to cloud. Any other new request will increment visit counter. So, if you expect less that 1400 requests within one month - 1 concurrent connection will be enough

Comment: In an android app, how can we know about firebase connection (such as when does a connection start and stop, how many connection does the app currently use and so on) ?

Comment: Are you trying to google something? The Firebase API does provide you with the goOffline and goOnline methods (https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#class_methods) - from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections

Comment: firebase free plan is as per month?

Answer (score 18):

From the same page where the question was copied/pasted:

> ### What is a concurrent connection?
>
> A connection is a measure of the number of users that are using your
>   app or site simultaneously. It's any open network connection to our
>   servers. This isn't the same as the total number of visitors to your
>   site or the total number of users of your app. In our experience, 1
>   concurrent corresponds to roughly 1,400 monthly visits.
>
> Our Hacker Plan has a hard limit on the number of connections. All of
>   the paid Firebases, however, are “burstable”, which means there are no
>   hard caps on usage. REST API requests don't count towards your
>   connection limits.

Data transfer refers to the amount of bytes sent back and forth between the client and server. This includes all data sent via listeners--e.g. on('child_added'...)--and read/write ops. This does not include hosted assets like CSS, HTML, and JavaScript files uploaded with `firebase deploy`

Data storage refers to the amount of persistent data that can live in the database. This also does not include hosted assets like CSS, HTML, and JavaScript files uploaded with `firebase deploy`

Comment: If firebase have max 100 connections, that mean only 100 user of my app may be connect to server to get data on time. Is it too small ?

Answer (score 16):

> These limits mentioned and discussed in the answers, are per project

The number of free projects is not documented. Since this is an abuse vector, the number of free projects is based on some super secret sauce--i.e. your reputation with Cloud. Somewhere in the range of 5-10 seems to be the norm.

Note also that deleted projects take around a week to be deleted and they continue to count against your quota for that time frame.
[Ref](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/wYQH_2uEPyI)