# What API Error is thrown when too many connections are received?

Tags: firebase

According to the Firebase website it says "When the 101st user tries to connect, the API will throw an error" when your connection limit is 100. What error is thrown, so I can handle it and display to the user that the servers are overloaded? I could not find it documented anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is response https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/4RjyYIDqMVQ  to in firebase dev.

there is no any way to handling this error in programmatically.to many error connection error is give by developer console when 101 connection active..
also refer this link [Limitation of free plan in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501794/limitation-of-free-plan-in-firebase?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Official "**Too Many Connections**" HTTP code is **HTTP 429**. If they followed the standard in the app you are using, you will get this error.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and search for 429

Other than that, 509 (Bandwidth exceeded), 503 (Service unavailable) or 450 (file busy)